# What is the best way to edit those 1 pixel background images?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsp, image-processing

I got my colleague's web page together with and the css files and many images. I need to apply part of it to my jsp page. I have to admit that I didn't have any experience in handling css. Currently I am using GIMP2 to edit those 1-pixel-width background images. It's really the pain in the neck. I have to guess the proper image size, crop it a bit, then view it in the jsp... Do you have a better way to edit those 1-pixel-width images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I should ask if there is a way that I can interactively change the background image and can see the effect on the jsp page preview. Note that I am currently using the Eclipse's web tool editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into using Firebug add on for Firefox. There you can tweak the height of the graphics while looking at the page (yes, you need some knowledge about the DOM, CSS and Firebug to fully get this, but it's worth learning). Once you're happy with it, you open up your image editor and crop the image to that height.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks for your advise. I actually have firebug installed but I thought I can only use it for viewing (not tweaking) the page layout and the scripts. Do you have any good resource/tutorial that I can have a read to learn how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Check http://getfirebug.com/css. Once you get a hang on tracking down that 1px image, you'll be able to manipulate its height etc. Firebug has a lot of goodies... manipulating the CSS is just one of them. :)

Comment: Thank you so much Gert!! I didn't know firebug is so powerful. the tweaking feature is so great. I also look at other firebug features in the provided site. All features are so great. Thanks!

Comment: No problem and I agree. :) Another very good companion is the Web Developer toolbar: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/ It has a lot of good Web development tools.